# Magento 1column layout woes

Tags: xml, magento, layout

Using a new install of Magento CE 1.7.0.2, I am trying to get my `PRODUCT PAGE` layout to 1 column without going through the admin panel and setting each individual product to 1 column layout.

What I have tried:

I have attempted to create a `local.xml` in my `layout` folder for my template.  That `local.xml` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>

    <my_category_root_template>
        <reference name="root">
            <tpl>page/1column.phtml</tpl>
        </reference>
    <my_category_root_template>

    <catalog_category_layered>
        <update handle="my_category_root_template" />
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
        <update handle="my_category_root_template" />
    </catalog_category_layered_nochildren>

    <catalog_category_default>
        <update handle="my_category_root_template" />
    </catalog_category_default>

    <!-- EDIT: forgot about search results page -->
    <catalogsearch_advanced_result>
        <update handle="my_category_root_template" />
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>

<layout>
```

I've also tried the instance of `2columns-right.phtml` and tried changing that to `1column.phtml` in `page.xml` to no avail.  Cache is disabled as it's a staging site, but I have manually removed `var/cache` just for good measure.  I know I am missing something here, but I just can't for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

catalog_product_view is the layout handle for product pages, to find the handle of page, look at the html body class.